# Is inverse function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $ f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be an injective function defined on an interval $I$. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $c \in I$. Is it necessary $f^{-1 } : f(I) \rightarrow I$  continuous at $f(c)$?

I know if we drop the condition $I$ is interval then there are counterexamples. But how to proceed in this case?

Comment: Try to build a counter example with a function such that the images of arbitrary small intervals centered at $c$ are not intervals.

Comment: If $f$ is globally continuous, then the result is true and (if I remember correctly) uses the fact that continuous injective maps defined on intervals are strictly monotone.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.

The problem is that $f$ may take values close to $f(c)$, at points which are far from $c$.

For example, take $I = \mathbb R$ and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if} \; x \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q \\
x &\text{if} \; x \in \mathbb Q \cap (-\infty, 0]\\
x^2 &\text{if} \; x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0, 1]\\
2(x-1)^2 & \text{if} x \in \mathbb Q \cap (1, +\infty) \,.\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is injective, but $f^{-1} : f(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ is not continuous at $0$, because $f^{-1}(2q^2) \approx 1$ for every $q \in \mathbb Q \cap f(\mathbb R)$, however small you take it.

Here, $f$ takes values that are close to $f(0)$ at points that are far from $0$ (points near $1$).